# Failure to send buffer region to REPL in sml-mode

Tags: emacs, sml

Recently I have started dabbling in the `sml-mode` Emacs package for running SML code. The problem I'm facing is when I try to send across a region of my SML code/file to the REPL (which I think is the only logical way of writing multi-line functions in SML without getting troubled by the primitive REPL). Here is my workflow:

- Open up an SML file (the SML mode shows in the bottom part of the window)
- Open up the REPL if it isn't already running (`C-c C-s`)
- Again get back to the SML file and write a function
- Select the entire function and then press `C-C C-r`. I get an error "Not a `sml-prog-proc` buffer"
- Now instead of selecting a region, just try to send the entire file to the REPL using `C-C C-l`; again the same error in the mini-buffer

Can someone please help me out in understand why this occurs and how to actually send across code from a script/file to the REPL when using SML? If it matters, I'm using SML/NJ.

TIA,
sasuke

Comment: you might wan't to add your version of emacs and sml-mode. I have followed your steps, and I can't reproduce your problems. Currently I'm using Version $Name$ of sml-mode, according to the sml-mode info :)... Acording to apt-cache i'm using version 4.1-2 and 23.3+1-1ubuntu9.1 of sml-mode and emacs respectively

Comment: When you select the entire function and press `C-c C-r`, what does the buffer's modeline say?  Does it still say the buffer is in "SML" mode?

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, it there is no change in the major mode; it shows something like `(SML Undo-Tree)`.

Comment: @Jesper.Reenberg: The emacs version is: 24.3.50.1; sml-mode version from the sml-mode.info file is: 4.13; OS version: Xubuntu 12.04 LTS. Hope that is sufficient info. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was bugging me as well, as it worked on some occasions but not on others.

If the *sml* process is killed with `C-d` (as recommended when issuing 'use' commands) and immediately restarted from the same buffer (`C-c C-s`), the error will occur whenever any of the 'send-to-repl' operations are performed.

The correct way (after killing the repl) is to switch back to the buffer containing the .sml file that is being edited and restart the repl from there (`C-c C-s`) or by either of (`C-c C-r`) or (`C-c C-l`).

HTH.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be do the trick but I'm wondering why it doesn't work if the REPL is killed and started without going in SML mode file. I'll wait for some time before accepting this answer. :)

Comment: From a brief look at the elisp code, the sml-prog-proc has to be linked with a buffer associated with a .sml file.  When the REPL is started from within itself,  there is no link between the code buffer and the REPL,  hence when trying to send to a REPL,  the code buffer hsa nowhere to send to.